# C#, getter/setter in List<cPoint> has error

Tags: c#, list, getter-setter

I have the following code: below is the struct of the point

```
public struct cPoint
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
}
```

Below is the Datasource class (snipped)

```
    public class DataSource
    {
        private List<cPoint> samples;               // Data buffer goes here.
        //---------------------------------------------------------Getter/Setter
        .....
        public List<cPoint> Samples { get { return samples; } set { samples = value; }}

        // =====================================================constructor
        public DataSource(int ilength, string sName, Color cLine)
        {
            samples = CreateList<cPoint>(length);         
        }
}
```

and then

```
public void CalcSinusFunction_Riscy(DataSource src, double Freq, double ampFactor)
{
    int sampleRate = src.Length;
    double amplitude = ampFactor * UInt16.MaxValue;
    double frequency = Freq;
    for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
    {
        src.Samples[i].x = i;
        src.Samples[i].y = (float)(amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * (float)i * frequency) / sampleRate));
    }
}
```

It highlight an error, I not sure what I done wrong here, any solution?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UDT_Term_FFT.cPoint>' to 'UDT_Term_FFT.cPoint[]'    UDT_Term_FFT    H:\007_ZMDI_Sync\007_ZMDI_zzDevelopment\002_Software\042_UDTermFFT-2C\UDTermFFT\ADT_Term_FFT\035_Scope\RiscyScope.cs    195
Error   CS1612  Cannot modify the return value of 'List<cPoint>.this[int]' because it is not a variable UDT_Term_FFT    H:\007_ZMDI_Sync\007_ZMDI_zzDevelopment\002_Software\042_UDTermFFT-2C\UDTermFFT\ADT_Term_FFT\035_Scope\RiscyScope.cs    143
Error   CS1612  Cannot modify the return value of 'List<cPoint>.this[int]' because it is not a variable UDT_Term_FFT    H:\007_ZMDI_Sync\007_ZMDI_zzDevelopment\002_Software\042_UDTermFFT-2C\UDTermFFT\ADT_Term_FFT\035_Scope\RiscyScope.cs    144
```

Comment: `implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UDT_Term_FFT.cPoint>' to 'UDT_Term_FFT.cPoint[]'` - You're likely trying to apply a `List<>` to an `array`. Goto the line and take appropriate steps to convert it. May seem like pretty "lame" advice but that's where the error is originating and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding first error: we need to know there is line 195? It seems like it beyond your sample. Basically you can use "ToArray()" extension method.

Second error occures because of cPoint is a structure.
[] operator of List always returns the copy of that structure. So it is useless to modefy that copy and then immidiatly lose it (since it was not stored in any variable).
You can change point by following code:

```
src.Samples[i] = new cPoint()
{
   x = i,
   y = (float)(amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * (float)i * frequency) / sampleRate))
};
```

Comment: Yes this method now make more sense now, sorry for earlier confusion, thank!.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this below method with yours, I hope this will be helpful to you.

```
 public void CalcSinusFunction_Riscy(DataSource src, double Freq, double ampFactor)
        {
            int sampleRate = src.Length;
            double amplitude = ampFactor * UInt16.MaxValue;
            double frequency = Freq;
            for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
            {
                var obj = src.Samples[i];
                obj.x = i;
                obj.y = (float)(amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * (float)i * frequency) / sampleRate));
                Console.WriteLine("Index {0}: x: {1}  y: {2}", i, obj.x, obj.y);
            }


        }
```

Comment: Yes that work, it smell of boxing/unboxing method. Maybe I'm wrong but unsure why this has to be done.

Comment: Sorry that did not work, the error went away but did not actually modify the value in the class object. I think it just create new object obj and put value there but did nothing to save data back into class object or instance.